# Found a SMTP server which host an email address but still get a Delivery Status code

Tags: email, dns, smtp

I want to send a mail to a user which email adress ends by **@thinc.local**, as I can't send this mail the usual way (for instance gmail discusses with Google MX server which doesn't recognize this address), I had to find a mail server which host this email address.

So I connected in SMTP (`telnet IP_add 25`) to different servers and I checked with VRFY or EXPN command if the email address was hosted by the server or not.

I had one server which responded "positively":

To `VRFY henry`:

```
252 <henry@thinc.local>
```

To `EXPN henry`:

```
250 <henry@thinc.local>
```

I know the IP_addr of the mail server AND the domain name (barry.thinc.local). So I tried to send an email to henry@thinc.local by adding this server to the outgoing SMTP server list in Thunderbird (I chose no security or authentication method, maybe this is a problem). But I still get a **Delivery Status** code message back.

I would like to have your opinion, because I'm feeling that I missed something.

P.S: I'm working in a training environment, so don't need to ask if I'm doing something illegal ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you seem to be missing is that `.local` names, by their very nature, are only known and visible *inside* your local network, thus there is no way that an "outside" mail server could ever resolve them properly, MX or no MX. (The `.local` domain is specifically reserved for this purpose.)

It's not just the name though – 99% of the time, these "local" names resolve to private IP addresses as well (e.g. 192.168.x.x or fe80::x or other ranges reserved by RFC 1918). So even if your chosen mail server *could* resolve the name, it still couldn't reach the actual address.

---

Remember that such "private" addresses are duplicated across many networks. Your home has an 192.168.1.1, your neighbour's LAN has a *different* 192.168.1.1, and several billion homes also have their own 192.168.1.1's.

The same situation is with `.local` names – the same `whatever.local` might mean different things in different places. Even if you *could* find a SMTP server that accepted mail to `.local` addresses, you still couldn't tell where it actually delivered them.

In other words, mailing `@thinc.local` via Gmail is like writing "To: J. Smith" on a paper letter and trying to send it through New York Postal Office or something.

---

So the short answer is, you must deliver the mail either *directly* (by connecting to `thinc.local:25`), or through a server that runs in the *same* LAN as the `thinc.local` computer is on.

Try the first option – a direct connection from your PC, either to the MX (well, I'm *guessing* the domain you mentioned is the MX for `thinc.local`) or to the domain itself:

```
telnet barry.thinc.local 25

telnet thinc.local 25
```

In fact, since you said you have the IP address, try connecting to that as well.

If that reaches the recipient, you're done.